# Joomla- Custom created session getting destroyed

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating a custom session in joomla using the following code:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();                 
$session->set( 'myvar', '123' );
```

Also, i am integrating the virtual merchant payment gateway in my site. But it is getting destroyed after getting redirect to the virtual merchant?

Any reason? And how can i protect my session in such a condition?

Comment: if you are using any third party payment gateway which will redirect to another server then this thing should not work.

Comment: yes i m getting this error. so how can i retain my session throughout the whole process?

Comment: no you cannot have the same session on another server.